Is free will skepticism self-refuting?
If humans are supposed to use reason to support their claims but lack free will then it seems like we don't exercise rational thought because we're not free to adjudicate from among the reasons. If this is the case, then our confidence in our beliefs seems to be undercut including our skepticism in free will, hence the self refutation. Is skepticism of free will a self-refuting position?

There is libertarian and compatibilist free will, and the question does not clarify if only one is meant, or either.

Free will is awkward to define outside the context of distributing moral responsibility between man and God. It may be helpful to skip "free will skepticism" and instead consider "naturalistic determinism" or "naturalistic stochastic determinism" to avoid the inevitable argumentum ad Heisenberg.

we are not exercising free will when we use our reason. Reason can lead you to only one conclusion, the one that is granted by the premise and a sound reasoning. None of this depends on us. It is not up to us to decide if "All men are mortal, Socrates is a man" implies that Socrates is mortal. Reasoning is probably one of the worst example when it comes to discussing free will.

The ability to "freely choose" between multiple answers (one correct and n wrong ones) is not necessary to produce the right answer. That's how computers produce correct answers.
The more freedom a reasoning entity had in choosing a wrong answer, the less it's answers should be trusted.
To be confident, we need the ability to check the result of our reasoning against some ground truth. That is sufficient. And if that is possible, then inability to freely choose wrong answers would warrant more confidence, not less. A deterministically learning algorithm would use both those 2 abilities, to check answers and to only pick correct inferences to infer the conclusion that it itself is fully deterministic.

To reason one needs assumptions, if you cannot evaluate which assumptions are true, but are predetermined by physical processes, akin to rolling a dice, to conclude which ones are true, you cannot expect your reasoning to lead you to any correct conclusions.

If you cannot evaluate which assumptions.are true, but you have all the "freedom" in the world, you'd still never know if your reasoning led to any correct conclusion.

You're correct, I haven't shown freedom solves that problem, however, you attempted to present lack of free will as more trustworthy and I have shown that is not the case but ultimately relies on who/what set the deterministic rules. So, assuming the rules are the result of deterministic physical processes as opposed to wilfully made to comport with reality, the deterministic system will make more errors.

Sure, any two imperfect systems will make any number of errors. But you don't explain how many errors any given deterministic system will make, nor how many a system with freedom will make, nor why all deterministic systems with errors would all make more errors than any "free" system. Evolutionists could point to evolution yielding systems with very low error rates, yet fully deterministic.

A computer program that plays chess or Go also needs to make choices. At each move, it has several choices, several possible continuations, several legal moves. It needs to plan ahead and model ("imagine") those choices and model relevant, likely responses. It needs to summarize and evaluate those plans in a heuristic and rational way, as far as possible, and select the move that seems "best" according to whatever further criteria of "best" it has.
A computer program obviously does not have a libertarian free will.
But do we need to make any assumptions about humans beyond these capabilities in order to explain human choice actions?
Suppose we define (libertarian) free will as follows:

"A subject has free will" = "When deliberating about what to do, the subject has certain options (of which the subject is aware as option). When and if a subject actually makes a choice (selects one of the options),
neither the fact that the subject selects one option (rather than doing nothing) nor the particular option that is selected in any way depend on physical causes - at least not in such a way that that fact (that an option is selected), or the particular selection could be predicted by anyone with any chance of being correct greater than by a random prediction."

(In "predicted by anyone" we could restrict this to "predicted by anyone other than the subject", though it's difficult and seems self-contradictory to assume that there could be actions that only the subject themselves could in principle predict. Wittgenstein's argument against the possibility of private languages might also be relevant in thise context. But to keep things a bit simpler, let's just restrict it to "predicted by someone other than the subject themselves".)
(Note that when we introduce a likelihood of making correct predictions, this really only makes sense when these scenarios -- choice actions and classes of choice actions -- are repeatable. But this is indeed exactly what we want. We're not talking about temporal singularities, even though this aspect of the problem also often seems to be ignored, especially by defenders of libertarian free will. It matters that we're speaking about repeatable actions and events.)
It seems obvious to me that this concept of free will sees choice actions as absolutely indeterministic, and thereby unpredictable (and  irrational). The problem is that this can not be a basis or a justification of moral responsibility or accountability. For instance, if someone promises to do something, the promise is only trustworthy if we know that the person is really committed ("determined") to keep it. Promising to do something implies making one's actions predictable to others and presupposes being able to predict one's own actions. Assuming that this is based on a libertarian free would undermine this, make it inexplicable that we ever trust anyone (inclusing ourselves) to keep their promises.
The phrase "making one's actions predictable" is not meant as some magical step, of course. It's tantamount to simply predicting one's own actions (either to oneself or someone else) and presenting them in the form of a social bond. (The performative speech act of 'promising' implies that one allows the other to demand accountability for breaking the promise, in case one breaks it later). But a subject cannot simply predict anything. There is always a context of "normalcy" (also usually ignored in the abstract defenses of libertarian free will).
For instance, an addict may sincerely belief they "have" certain options and promise themselves or someone else "I will never smoke again", but this may not be a very reliable prediction. (I wonder how many believers in 'libertarian free will' have ever struggled to overcome a real addiction.) In daily life, in actual choice actions, "having options a and b" need not be as clear cut as libertarians might need it to be.
In short, if free will is understood as "libertarian free will", rather than "compatibilist free will", skepticism of free will does not refute itself. It's rather the reverse: libertarian free will makes choices actions inexplicable, and thereby, in a sense, refutes itself.

Yes; here is one way that a free will skeptic generally undercuts himself.  I don't remember who first said it, but I remember hearing that if we have no free will, our beliefs are like soda fizz bubbling over a glass; what we think is ultimately determined by blind chemical processes.  Differences in opinion are reduced to differences in inputs and to individual "quirks" in the way each person's brain calculates answers.  But if that's the case, who's to say that one "soda fizz" is more "true" than any other?  Who's to say of the person that fundamentally disagrees, that he is any less correct?  Their "soda fizz" is just different, and no less determined.  And that includes the very skepticism of free will itself.
Thus, a person cannot consistently hold that free will skepticism is true, let alone argue why others should adopt it as a matter of truth.  All he can consistently say is that the inputs into his thinking, coupled with the individual quirks of his brain's complex processes, have produced skepticism of free will in his particular case.

"what we think is ultimately determined by blind chemical processes" - processes that are us. Were you able to resist the subtle, perhaps unconscious temptations to post your answer here? (Did you actually first deliberate about posting or not posting? Or in choosing each word, weigh which word to choose?) Of course you can imagine you might have not posted anything (or might have changed your wording) - but in fact, you did post something. Do you know all the causes that led to that?

Since most of those causes are part of who or what you are, is it then necessary to assume that anything apart from having imagination is needed to make a choice?

@mudskipper--The point I was going for wasn't the inherent irrationality of the idea of deterministic choice.  I grant it can exist if defined that way (e.g., in computers, as you mention).  The point I was going for is that it is inherently irrational for us to argue against our own free will, because if our beliefs are determined, then our very skepticism of free will cannot be trusted to be based in truth; it is merely the "fizz" bubbling up from our unique chemistry and mental inputs.

I don't see how you can infer from "thoughts are determined" to "thoughts can not be based in truth". A long process of random selection and concatenation of letters (a group of monkeys typing) can generate any finite-length empirical report. So, the causal history of how a proposition comes to be does not seem relevant for determining its truth-value... (I am that "fizzing" you speak of.)

@mudskipper I agree that a deterministic belief could happen to be true regardless of its history.  My point is that if all belief is determined, there's no way for anyone to know which beliefs are true.  The very view of truth would also be determined.  Two people vigorously disagree, and there would be no way to know who is right, since both opinions are determined by nature.  Thus, to argue against our own free will is inherently irrational, because that very belief itself would be determined just as much if it were false as if it were true.

Peter - I understand your point, but it just makes no sense to me. To determine whether or not something is true in empirical science, we use certain criteria -- measurements, repeatable observations -- None of that changes, if determinism is (partially or completely) true. We can still use the same criteria. Then as long as those are clear enough, and we follow the same procedures, and are not delusional etc, we can predict we will reach the same conclusions - as in fact we do (often).

@mudskipper Well, if we're talking about something where virtually no one disagrees, such as the boiling point of water at sea level, then we don't use reason to persuade each other anyway, and bias can't come into play.  But in areas where people do disagree after seeing all of the same evidence and arguments, how could a determinist possibly know that it isn't he himself who has missed the mark in that topic...that he wasn't determined to see it all wrong somehow?  After all, the other "computers" output their different answers with as much conviction, and given the same input.

I guess - just like the Mormons - I have not yet given up the hope that I might convert someone else to see things by the light of physicalism :)

My couple of cents.
Indeed there is something problematic in arguing for the non-existence of (libertarian) free will, something that has been pointed out, even by Kant himself, using transcendental arguments.
For example, THE TRANSCENDENTAL REFUTATION OF DETERMINISM argument, by William Hasker, goes along these lines.

[...] One of the most striking of these refutations [of determinism]
claims to establish a logical incompatibility between determinism and
such key epistemic notions as knowledge, rational inference, justified
belief, and the like. This "transcendental" refutation of determinism
has been known as least since Kant, yet in spite of its potentially
decisive nature it has been somewhat neglected in the literature.
Determinists have been less eager to meet it than one might think they
ought to be, and on the other hand the argument has not always been
presented as rigorously as might be wished. My contention is that,
with two qualifications, the argument is conclusive.

Ibrahim Dagher has expanded this argument in Expanding William Hasker’s Transcendental Refutation of Determinism.

This paper is an evaluation and expansion of William Hasker’s
transcendental argument against determinism. Hasker’s argument
attempts to show that determinism is logically incompatible with
rationality and justified belief. Hasker claims this argument to be
conclusive given two independent qualifications: first that the
argument only applies to a specific form of determinism, and second
that the argument rests on a specific conception of rationality. My
aim in this paper will be to modify and expand Hasker’s argument such
that it (1) applies to the more general deterministic thesis (as
defined below), and (2), rests on a modified epistemic conception of
rationally unaffirmable beliefs. I will attempt to do (2) by modeling
Hasker’s argument after one of Alvin Plantinga’s epistemological
arguments against naturalism, and hope to show that such an
argumentative model is superior for the conclusion Hasker wishes to
bring out. I will begin by explicating Hasker’s argument, and then I
will move to the modification and expansion of the argument.

Similarly, in A rationalist argument for libertarian free will by Stylianos Panagiotou it is argued against (strict) determinism (and for libertarian free will) but therein the transcendental argument results in an ontological result and claim.

In this thesis, I give an a priori argument in defense of libertarian
free will. I conclude that given certain presuppositions, the ability
to do otherwise is a necessary requirement for substantive
rationality; the ability to think and act in light of reasons.
‘Transcendental’ arguments to the effect that determinism is
inconsistent with rationality are predominantly forwarded in a Kantian
manner. Their incorporation into the framework of critical philosophy
renders the ontological status of their claims problematic; rather
than being claims about how the world really is, they end up being
claims about how the mind must conceive of it. To make their
ontological status more secure, I provide a rationalist framework that
turns them from claims about how the mind must view the world into
claims about the ontology of rational agents. In the first chapter, I
make some preliminary remarks about reason, reasons and rationality
and argue that an agent’s access to alternative possibilities is a
necessary condition for being under the scope of normative reasons. In
the second chapter, I motivate rationalism about a priori
justification. In the third chapter, I present the rationalist
argument for libertarian free will and defend it against objections.
Several objections rest on a compatibilist understanding of an agent’s
abilities. To undercut them, I devote the fourth chapter, in which I
give a new argument for incompatibilism between free will and
determinism, which I call the situatedness argument for
incompatibilism. If the presuppositions of the thesis are granted and
the situatedness argument works, then we may be justified in thinking
that to the extent that we are substantively rational, we are free in
the libertarian sense.

Furthermore it should be pointed out that having a choice over a result does not make it more "wrong" than having no choice whatsoever (as has been suggested by some people). The simple reason is that having a free choice on a matter can on the average lead to optimum outcomes over a sufficiently large number of cases, since bad outcomes have multiple choices of being avoided and good outcomes multiple choices of being reached (assuming the goal is set), than being fully determined and pre-disposed to certain outcomes, which may not be optimum, and this is certain, on average, by statistical arguments both over a sufficiently large number of, in general, different cases, and over a sufficently large number of, in general, different agents.

free will or the lack of thereof does not contradict reason, it gives it another meaning. lacking free will and reason is not much more than being a rock, though keeping reason basically means that we make decisions or take beliefs based on what we already know, and compile it together with our pre-existing values to come up with a an answer to any problem.
skepticism against free will means that through this type of reasoning, a person concluded that their decisions are not through free will but by rational, though often flawed from lack of knowledge or incorrect beliefs, reasoning. I hope this is an insightful answer

Lacking free will one would not be able to do anything that would require making choices.
A belief is a choice, a claim is a choice, skepticism is a choice, reasoning is a series of choices.
This means that free will skepticism is self-refuting.

This is a circular argument. Free will is smuggled in along with the definition of 'choice'. If you are trying to make the case that determinists assume free choice by claiming to be rational you need to elaborate.

Nothing circular, nothing smuggled. Free will is the ability to make choices. Determinists assume there is no such thing as choice. I am not trying to make a case, I am only answering the question

This answer which again pushes personal beliefs merely refutes lack of free will. But that does not show it's SELF-refuting. So missing the topic again. The question was NOT whether we have free will, or whether life without free will is possible.

@tkruse Why do you behave like a regular PIA? Nothing in my answer is a personal belief. I did establish that it is self-refuting:  Expressing skepticism requires free will. You cannot be skeptical about your ability to be skeptical.

A belief is a choice? When I have perceptions, I chose to have those perceptions?
Moore's paradox "It's raining but I don't belief it" is not a paradox?

@mudskipper Holding something true without compelling evidence is a choice.

So is perception also equal to "holding something true without compelling evidence"?

Perception, I believe, is just about same thing as interpretation, which is a choice.

On the other hand, if belief were a choice then there would be no rationale to believe it, leading to a contradiction. Richard Swinburne argues a strong form of this (which I don’t quite follow) but claims that Hume believed at least a weak version of it.

@tkruse The concept of "unfree choice" is a meaningless oxymoron and it was not mentioned in the question for good reason. Only you brought it up for no reason.

@tkruse Why do you hate me? Why do you constantly downvote me and make these preposterous claims about me? What do you expect to gain from these ad hominem attacks? Stick to the subject, correct mistakes, be constructive, behave.
